# How to go through many objects in R

Tags: r, loops

I'm new to R, and I have 20 .csv files that I created after an experiment I conducted. The files names follow this format "p01_results.csv", and I successfully imported them all to my global environment each as a dataset with the same name. Right now I'm trying to find an efficient way to remove 4 rows and add 2 columns. I know how to do it for each dataset individually as you can see below, but I don't know how to do it through a loop of some sort.

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
list2env( lapply(setNames(temp, make.names(gsub("*.csv$", "", temp))), 
read.csv), envir = .GlobalEnv)

p01_results <- p01_results[-c(1 , 20 , 39 , 58) , ]

p01_results$p <- rep(1, 72)

p01_results$s <- c(rep(1,18), rep(2,18), rep(3,18), rep(4,18))
```

Comment: First step would be not to read these all into separate variables. This just makes everything in R more difficult. Don't use `list2env`. Just leave them in the list and apply your transformation function over that list. Having a list of values is much easier to use than a bunch of loose variables in your environment.

Comment: my aim is to add a participant column "p" to each dataset and all its values would 1 for the first participant and so on, also each participant had 4 sessions each with 18 tasks, so I wanted to add an "s" column to mark the sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather follow a `list` approach followed by the use of `lapply()`. Something like:

```
results = vector("list",20)
for (i in 1:20){
     if (i<10) { file = paste0("p0",i,"_results.csv")} else {file = paste0("p",i,"_results.csv")
     results[[i]] = read.csv(file)
}

results = lapply(results,function(x){x <- x[-c(1 , 20 , 39 , 58) , ]

x$p <- rep(1, 72)

x$s <- c(rep(1,18), rep(2,18), rep(3,18), rep(4,18))
})
```

Comment: If you are recommending `lapply`, why not something like `lapply(sprintf("p%02d_results.csv", 1:20), read.csv)`?

Comment: gave it a try, there was an error "Error in x[-c(1, 20, 39, 58), ] : incorrect number of dimensions"

Comment: If you could give some reproducible example I can check why its not working

Comment: Do you mean a sample csv file from my dataset?

Comment: yeah or at least a `dput()` of what you get in `R` from your csv.

Comment: how would I post this here?

Comment: decided to do it in python. it might be easier.